# Executor.map on concurrent futures is not processed

Tags: python-3.6, concurrent.futures

I cannot understand why a simple Executor won't work

I have two modules: `main.py`

```
import other

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b'] 
l = ['a', 'b', 'd']

other.run_executor(a, b, l)
```

And `other.py`

```
from concurrent import futures
from multiprocessing import cpu_count


def do_stuff(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)


def run_executor(a, b, l):
    iterat = ((a, b, c) for c in l)
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=cpu_count() - 1) as e:
        e.map(do_stuff, iterat)
```

Running this code raises no error, but also does not print anything.
It shoud print a, b, l[0]; a, b, l[1]; a, b, l[2]
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are not using `ThreadPoolExecutor.map` properly. The arguments should not be passed as one iterator but as 3 iterators:

```
from concurrent import futures
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import cpu_count


def do_stuff(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)


def run_executor(a, b, l):
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=cpu_count() - 1) as e:
        e.map(do_stuff, repeat(a), repeat(b), c)
```

Also, you should use the `if __name__ == "__main__"` protection in your main script to avoid weird behaviors. This permit to protect your module main from executing if you try to import/pickle a function defined in it.

```
import other

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = ['a', 'b'] 
    l = ['a', 'b', 'd']

    other.run_executor(a, b, l)
```

Comment: Thanks, It did work. BUT. Again, I can't restrain it to main... It has to be called from another module (without protection). What is 'weird behavior'? As I said in the other question; My full program is as follows: main.py initiates the process. then a parametrization is called, then agents are loaded or created, then a time iteration module takes place. Time iteration calls running_month where I need `do_stuff()`. On top of that, on multiple simulation, I call `main.py` 100 times.In sum, the ordering of events prevent me from having do_stuff inside `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Comment: The only constraint here is that you don't want to create multiple pools of workers. When you import a module, all code that is not a function is run immediately. Thus if your code spawning the process is directly in a script, you can end up with errors or unintended behaviors. You should not run multiple time your script `main.py` but create a function `main()` you can import and that handles the computations. Creating a function instead of a script permits having the same safe guard as the `if main`.

Comment: Great. Excellent!

Comment: Now, I get stack overflow (literally) and had to expand the recursion limit (I don't know why). But, after all, it seems that neither `Threading` nor `Pooling` helped with performance and time which was my main concern. One run with 10% of a metropolis run may take 9 full days to run... That's why I was looking for faster ways...